# Use a helper to set a css class

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to make reactive a `class` inside a `const` (exported from a module).

```js
export const messageControls = '
    <div id="controls"">
        <i id="idcont" class="{{starred}}"></i>
    </div>
'
```

This `class` belongs to an HTML block who's inserted as `innerHTML` of a `createElement`.

```js
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.id = i._id;
newElement.className = "single_message";
newElement.innerHTML = messageControls;               
document.getElementById('conversation_details').appendChild(newElement);
```

The `{{helper}}` below is not rendering anything :

```js
starred: function () {
    return 'bob';
},
```

- `<i id="idcont" class="{{starred}}"></i>` gives `{{starred}}` in plain text
- `<i id="idcont" class=" ' + {{starred}} + ' "></i>` breaks all

Any idea?

**Update - full Blaze template as requested**

```
<template name="inbox">
    <div class="searchmessages">
        <input type="text" name="searchmessages" id="searchmessages" placeholder="&nbsp;&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;any word / any date">
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-4 l-O list_messages">
            <div id="gridreceived" class="gridmessages">
                {{#each incoming_all}}
                    <div id="{{_id}}" class="item {{readornot}}">
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="task_inlist">
                                <div class="task_from">
                                    {{{from}}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="task_date">
                                    {{initialdate}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="task_subject">
                                    {{{subject}}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="task_content">
                                    {{{htmlbody}}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <div class="grid_nomatch">{{grid_noresult}}</div>
        </div>

        <div id="conversation_details" class="col-xs-8" media="print">
            <!--
            here are each selected message details
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use blaze? Why are you building the DOM with code? Please show your blaze template code.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I do use Blaze & build the Dom with code to manage details of messages in the half right of the page, according to the message selected in the list of all messages in the left of the page (like an email client as Apple Mail or Outlook). I'll update my question with the blaze template - but he's pretty empty cause there is a lot of Dom building...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to inject spacebars template markup directly into the DOM but meteor-blaze wants to use spacebars to build the DOM. It doesn't watch the DOM for arbitrary changes and then make template substitutions inside of it!

You can instead use Meteor's *reactivity* to automatically insert new items into the DOM for you based on changes to the underlying data. In your case it looks like you're trying to show the details of a message that's been clicked on. You probably have a template event handler already to catch the click. In that template handler you can set a `Session` variable which indicates which message is currently selected and then use that Session variable inside the helper that renders the message details.

For example:

```
<template name="inbox">
  <div class="searchmessages">
    <input type="text" name="searchmessages" id="searchmessages" placeholder="&nbsp;&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;any word / any date">
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4 l-O list_messages">
      <div id="gridreceived" class="gridmessages">
        {{#each incoming_all}}
          <div id="{{_id}}" class="item {{readornot}}">
            // render summary of each message
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    <div class="grid_nomatch">{{grid_noresult}}</div>

    {{#with selectedMessage}}
      <div id="conversation_details" class="col-xs-8" media="print">
        // render selected message details
      </div>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Your js:

```
Template.inbox.events({
  'click .item'(ev) {
    Session.set('selectedMessageId',this._id);
  }
});

Template.inbox.helpers({
  selectedMessage() {
    return Messages.findOne(Session.get('selectedMessageId'));
  }
});
```

Now to your follow-up question about how to reactively *style* an element. Let's say your `message* object has a`isStarred`boolean key. In the message detail section we've set the data context using`{{#with currentMessage}}` so any key of the current message can be used directly in our spacebars template. Where you are displaying the message details you can do:

```
<div id="controls"">
    <i id="idcont" class="{{#if isStarred}}starred{{/if}}"></i>
</div>
```

Depending on whether or not the message is starred this will render as `class=""` or `class="starred"`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, "meteor-blaze wants to use spacebars to build the DOM", so inject a spacebar into a DOM is pointless. I like your explanation, actually I manage it by just getting the id of the message clicked in his `attr`. But my question is beyond that: in the rendered message, I would like to reactively render a star icon (plain or empty) based on the status of the selected message ('starred' field in coll.). The star icon is in a button who makes the message starred or not: so first render of the icon is ok, but after status change (like starred to unstarred) on button click, not.

Comment: Thanks for the update of your answer: I never realized it was possible to use `if then` statements in things as class name - but of course.